# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Flutter Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: Picture of my error]

Hello, could you help me with this error, I don't know how to solve it

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class Users {
  String id;
  String email;
  String name;
  String phone;

  Users({
    this.id,
    this.email,
    this.name,
    this.phone,
  });

  Users.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    id = dataSnapshot.key;
    email = dataSnapshot.value["email"];
    name = dataSnapshot.value["name"];
    phone = dataSnapshot.value["phone"];
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure "value" is what you're looking for? The auto complete will tell you which type is it. DataSnapshot is not a map... don't expect to use it as such. Is a complex object with many variables.

Comment: You need to share your database model as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Users.fromSnapShot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    var data = dataSnapshot.value as Map?;
    id = dataSnapshot.key;
    email = data?["email"];
    name = data?["name"];
    phone = data?["phone"];
    print("Users email $email");
    print("Users name $name");
    print("Users phone $phone");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot-class.html), `DataSnapshot.value` is a type `Object?`. This type doesn't define an indexer like `List` or `Map` does, so you can't use an indexer on it.

However, since `Object` is the superclass of everything, `value` could be typed as `Object` but actually be a `Map`. You can try to cast it to a `Map` first if you like, but you should only do this if you know that it is a `Map`. If it's not, then casting it will result in a runtime error. (You can do `print(dataSnapshot.value.runtimeType)` and see what it says before you make your decision.)